# Code Signing with a Certum certificate

Tags: windows, code-signing, code-signing-certificate, signtool

I want to sign a static .exe build of one of my Open Source programs so that it will be executable in a "normal" manner to a "normal" Windows user.

I bought an Open Source Code Signing Certificate from certum.eu to be able to do this.

After some searching on the internet, I tried to sign the exe file using osslsigncode 1.7.1 on my Linux maching using

```
osslsigncode sign -pkcs12 cert.p12 -pass "..." -h sha2 -t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll -in some.exe -out some-signed.exe
```

Having somebody testing it on Windows 10, a rough warning pops up: "Windows protected your PC. Windows SmartScreen prevented an unrecognized app 
from starting. Running this app might put your PC at risk."

So I tried to use the native Windows tool signtool.exe to sign it. I installed it in my old virtual Windows XP (where I also compiled the program; I don't have access to any other Windows machine) and signed the exe file with

```
"C:\Programme\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\signtool.exe" sign /f C:\cert.p12 /p "..." /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll C:\some.exe
```

This tool also said everything was okay, but still, the very same warning pops up.

This way, the certificate is simply useless, as the "signed" exe file does produce the very same warning as the unsigned one. I would greatly appreciate help about this.

Comment: May I ask you, do you use your Certum cert with a smart card, if so, what model of smart card? I have tried to buy and use one, but the only way I saw was to buy their smart card and then the price became too high for me. Is there a way to use Certum open code cert without smartcard or with non-certum's smartcard?

Comment: I bought it at the time one could simply download the cert via a browser. I think they changed it shortly after.

Comment: @vinsa, did you eventually buy the Certum certificate and, if so, was it with or without card and reader? I'm trying to understand what this card and reader is for and whether it's really needed, as it's not mentioned anywhere else on the internet (this is so weird, I can find zero information about this).

Comment: @this.lau_ I have paid for open code sign certificate by Certum, but without the reader and smartcard kit, and I was unable to use it, so in order to use their certificate, you have to buy the kit. I tried to use my own card reader and a cryptographic smartcard which I had but it was not working, so I had wanted a money refund. Btw I had to open a Paypal disput in order to get my money back, it is not easy. It will be more cheap with Comodo, they don't require to buy cardreader and smartcard there are resellers like [comodosslstore.com](http://comodosslstore.com) where the price is really low

Comment: @vinsa, thanks a lot for the information, it's good to know. Altogether the Certum certificate with card/read and shipping fees was around 130 EUR which is surprisingly high for what's supposed to be a cheap open source certificate. Based on your comment I've searched for a cheap Comodo certificate in my country and found one for £62 [here](https://cheapsslsecurity.co.uk/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Short answer: Wait a couple of days and the problem will disappear.

I had the same issue with my Certum certificate earlier this year.  And a few years ago, I had a commercial certificate I got from Comodo and it initially had the same issue as well.

The bottom line is that your new certificate and signed binaries needs some time to gain trust and auto-verified by Microsoft's code-signing reputation service.

Start distributing your signed exe to as many PC as you can and do the "advanced" option to force the exe to run anyway. That might help bump the reputation up faster.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info! Then I hope that it will work in a few days … is the way I signed the exe okay? Or asking in another way: Can I use osslsigncode as well as the Windows tool? And what is it with the hash function? osslsigncode can use the sha256 hash, with signtool.exe, I can't … (sorry for all the questions, the last Windows I actually used was 2000 ;-)

Comment: Looks good to me.  With `signtool.exe`, I think I used `/fd sha256` on the command line.  I think I read somewhere that using sha256 was preferred.  If you right click on the exe file in Windows Explorer, you can inspect the signature by looking at the Digital Signature tab.  I would stick with `signtool.exe`, but that's only because I don't have any experience with `osslsigncode`

Comment: I can't use sha256 with signtool.exe, because the version that can be installed on Windows XP is too old ;-) Let's hope for the best …

Comment: Also, I think to get the reputation service primed, you likely need to make sure the signed binary is "downloaded" consistently through a link on a web page (preferably Edge or IE as browser) and then run for the reputation service to pick up on the usage. You might get a different experience depending on Chrome vs IE/Edge vs manually copying the file with USB stick.

Comment: For an Open Source guy like me, that Windows system is really weird. But it's difficult to know what to do. I simply released my software and signed the Windows release with Windows (XP) tools using "signtool.exe sign /f cert.p12 /p ... /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll some.exe". Still, today, the same warning pops up. Let's see … perhaps, it takes some more days. If you should be interested, it can be found on http://nasauber.de/opensource/muckturnier/ btw … (perhaps you could have a look at it and tell me if it's signed correctly?)

Comment: I managed to setup a Windows 7 virtual machine and to double-sign the exe with SHA1 and SHA256. This actually is valid for Windows XP and 7. And the only thing left is that my software is dangerous, because it's not downloaded very often (Microsoft logic). Thanks for the info :-)